# How can I remove subsequent duplicate rows from a table in a sorted order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FreqLeeds] (
    [Id]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [Freq] DECIMAL (18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The data in the Text column should be unique but it is not.  Is there a way that I can retain the first value of `Text` (when sorted in the order of `Freq`) and remove all other rows with duplicate values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a `CTE` to do this:

```
;with cte
as (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by [Text] order by [Freq]
            ) rn
    from [dbo].[FreqLeeds] t
    )
delete
from cte
where rn <> 1
```

It will keep one row per `[Text]` with *minimum* `[Freq]` and delete all other rows. If you want to keep one row per `[Text]` with *maximum* `[Freq]`, then use `order by [Freq] desc` in the window function.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need unique index key.

But first of all, you need clear the duplicate items; then create unique index to prevent future dirty data:

```
-- Create a unique index 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_freqleeds_text   
   ON dbo.FreqLeeds ([Text]);   
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Id and Text values :

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY Text ORDER BY Freq ASC) as Id,
       MIN(Freq) as Freq,
       Text 
    FROM FreqLeeds 
    GROUP BY Text 
    ORDER BY Freq
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx